# How to mock the data from a helper method call while performing an Rspec test on a main method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec2

I'm trying to get the data suppose an array [1,2,3,4] from a method say ***helper***, that is called by a main ruby method called ***basic***, which is supposed to use that array that is being returned. How do i specify or hard code that array while writing tests for basic method?

Answer (score 0):

mock your dependency or message call

```
allow(self).to receive(:helper).with(params) or use (with_any) .and_return([1,2,3,4]).
```

Find more for rspec2 @ https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-99/docs/method-stubs/allow-with-a-simple-return-value

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! is the 'self' syntax correct? also does this mean that whenever the test calls the main method in the test body, the helper methods return value will be memorized as [1,2,3,4]?